# Qt - How to build a multi-tab window?

Tags: qt

I want to build a single-window application which has two tabs. How can I set two tabs on the window and click to switch, just like the browser's window and tabs ?

PS: The two tabs have different layout of buttons and text-widgets and functions differently.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#details

> The `QTabWidget` class provides a stack of tabbed widgets.
>
> A tab widget provides a tab bar (see `QTabBar`) and a "page area" that
>   is used to display pages related to each tab. By default, the tab bar
>   is shown above the page area, but different configurations are
>   available (see `TabPosition`). Each tab is associated with a different
>   widget (called a page). Only the current page is shown in the page
>   area; all the other pages are hidden. The user can show a different
>   page by clicking on its tab or by pressing its Alt+letter shortcut if
>   it has one.
>
> The normal way to use `QTabWidget` is to do the following:
>
> 1. Create a `QTabWidget`.
> 2. Create a `QWidget` for each of the pages in the tab dialog, but do not specify parent widgets for them.
> 3. Insert child widgets into the page widget, using layouts to position them as normal.
> 4. Call `addTab()` or `insertTab()` to put the page widgets into the tab widget, giving each tab a suitable label with an optional keyboard
>      shortcut.
>
> The position of the tabs is defined by `tabPosition`, their shape by
>   `tabShape`.
>
> ...

And there is your answer.

EDIT: Link to an example, too.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-tabdialog-example.html

Update: In addition to all the advantages that come with using the `QTabWidget`, some additional functionality of tabs come with the `QDockWidget`, like tearing them off into a separate window.  I've used `QDockWidgets` recently to get nearly the same appearance of tabs, but the baked in tear-off, and the right click for a checked listing of tabs.

Hope that helps.